# Como fazer o componente p:poll não interferir no modal em Primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tenho uma página que possui uma tabela no centro, essa tabela é atualizada a cada 30 segundos usando o componente `p:poll`

```
<p:poll interval="30" update=":centro" />
```

O problema é que tenho um menu que abre um popup (modal) com um formulário para ser preenchido.Se o usuário está preenchendo esse formulário e ocorre o update do pool, então tudo que o usuário digitou é perdido.

Tem alguma forma de não ocorrer o update nesse modal?

Já tentei deixar o modal fora do "centro" mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Este é um comportamento esperado, já que o código HTML do elemento atualizado e seus filhos é substituído por um novo no evento `update`.

Se o modal estava fora do centro ele não deveria ter sido fechado. Você tentou usar o atributo `appendTo="@body"`?

Entretanto, se atributos do ManagedBean forem alterados que o formulário do modal usa, o mesmo ficará fora de sincronia com o backend.

A única solução fácil que vejo para esse cenário, seria [desabilitar/habilitar o poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf) quando o usuário abrisse e fechasse a edição.